# javascript alert messages is not show in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am working on accounting project in mvc3 and wcf services. i am using javascript,ajax for form validation. i write the code for validate form in javascript. but my javascript alerts are not shown to user.although i enable javascript in brwoser. while i debug the code then javascript lerts was show but without debugging code if form is submit then alert messages for validation are not display to me.

below is the code of form in mvc3

```
@model CBS.Models.AccntBD

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AccCode";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AccCode</h2>

<div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table class="tablestyle">
    <tr>
<td>   
<label>Account Code</label>
</td>
<td>
              <input type="text" id="AcCode" name="AcCode" maxlength="10" placeholder="Account     Code" autofocus="true" class="required" />

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AcCode)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
 <label>Description</label>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" id ="Descrip" name="Descrip" maxlength="150" placeholder="Desription..."     class="Descrip"/>
              @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Descrip) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descrip)
</td>
</tr>
   <tr>
   <td>
   <span>
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel()" />
   </span>           
          <span>
         <input type="submit" id="sve" name="action" value="Save" />
        </span>
         <span>
         <input type="submit" id="edi" value="Edit" name="action"/>             
        </span>
   <span>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="del" name="action"/>
   </span>
        </td>
       <td>
   </td>
         </tr>  
   <tr>
   <td>       
                           @ViewData["result"]
              </td>
   <td>
   @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")

   </td>
   </tr>
</table>     
    }
    </div>
@section PageScripts{
<script src="/Scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

}
```

below is my test.js file code

```
  $('#sve').click(function () {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var isValid = validateForm();
    if (isValid) {

        //***********************CODE TO SAVE DATA IN DATABASE***********************************
        var person = { AcCode: $('#AcCode').val(), Descrip: $('#Descrip').val(), AddOn: dd };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Save?action=Sve',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(person),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                //   $('#message').html('Record saved successfully' + result).fadeIn();
                alert("Record saved successfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                //    $('#message').html('Error Occurred').fadeIn(); 
                alert("Record not saved successfully");
            }
        });
    }
    else
        return false;

});  //end button clcik function

function GetCodeData(Str) {

    var p = {
        StrSql: Str

    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetGenVal',
        type: 'POST',
        // contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: false,
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(p),
        cache: false,
        //   success: callback
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#Descrip").val(data);
            //  ResSubCode = data;
            strRes = null;
            strRes = data;
            return strRes;
        }

    });
}


 function validateForm() {
    //==================CHCK EMPTY OR NULL OF ACCOUNT CODE FIELD===========================
    if ($('#AcCode').val().trim().length === 0) {
        alert('Must enter Account Code');
        $('#AcCode').focus();
        return false;
    } //end if
    //==================CHCK EMPTY OR NULL OF DESCRIPTION FIELD===========================
    if ($('#Descrip').val().trim().length === 0) {
        alert('Must enter Description');
        $('#Descrip').focus();
        return false;
    } //end if

    //==========================CHEK ACCOUNT CODE DIGITS=============================================
    subA = $('#AcCode').val().trim();
    //===========================check whether code exist already or not
    if (subA.length === 10) {
        str1 = "select AcCode from Account where AcCode='";
        str2 = str1 + subA + "'";
        GetCodeData(str2); //check whether code exist or not
        strRes = strRes.substring(1, strRes.length - 1);
        if (strRes.length > 0 && strRes != "") //if  code exist then return false and not allow to enter code   
        {
            alert('Code already exist cannot insert record');
            return false;
        }

    }
    //===============================
      if (subA.length === 2) {
        str1 = "select AcCode from Account where AcCode='";
        str2 = str1 + subA + "'";
        GetCodeData(str2); //check whether code exist or not
        strRes = strRes.substring(1, strRes.length - 1);
        if (strRes.length > 0 && strRes != "") //if  code exist then return false and not allow to enter code   
        {
            alert('Code already exist cannot insert record');
            return false;
        }

    }
    //============================
      if (subA.length === 4) {
        str1 = "select AcCode from Account where AcCode='";
        str2 = str1 + subA + "'";
        GetCodeData(str2); //check whether code exist or not
        strRes = strRes.substring(1, strRes.length - 1);
        if (strRes.length > 0 && strRes != "") //if  code exist then return false and not allow to enter code   
        {
            alert('Code already exist cannot insert record');
            return false;
        }

    }
    //=====================================end of code existence checking


    if (subA.length === 10) {//if user enter complete code
        sub4 = subA.slice(0, 4); //take first 4 digits of account code to check "0000"
        if (sub4 === '0000') {
            alert('Complete Code cannot Start with 0000');
            return false;
        } //end of chek first 4 digits are 0 or not
        //===================================================
        sub2 = subA.slice(0, 2); //get first 2 digits of account code
        // alert(sub2);
        str1 = "select AcCode from Account where AcCode='";
        str2 = str1 + sub2 + "'";
        GetCodeData(str2); //check whether 2 digits code exist or not
        //       alert(strRes);
        strRes = strRes.substring(1, strRes.length - 1);
        if (strRes.length > 0 && strRes != "") //if 2 digit code exist then chk for 4 digit code otherwise give message to create 2 digit code
        {
            var result;
            strRes = null;
            str2 = null;
            sub4 = subA.slice(0, 4); //get first 4 digits of account code
            str2 = str1 + sub4 + "'";
            result = Chk4DigitCode(str2)
            if (!result) {
                return false;
            }


            //                GetCodeData(str2); //check whether 4 digits code exist or not
            //                strRes = strRes.substring(1, strRes.length - 1);
            //                alert(strRes);
            //                if (strRes.length < 0) {
            //                    alert("First Create Sub Code of First Four Digits");
            //                    // alert("First Create Sub Code of First Four Digits");
            //                    //display message for create 4 digit sub code
            //                    //alert("");
            //                    //return false;

            //                }
        }
        else
            alert("First Create Control Code of Two Digits"); //display message for create 2 digit sub code
        return false;
    } //end of check length of code is 10
    //=================================
    else if (subA.length === 4) { //check whether user enter sub code
        sub2 = null;
        sub2 = subA.slice(0, 2);
        if (sub2 === '00') {
            alert('Sub Code cannot Start with 00');
            return false;
        } //end of chek first 2 digits are 0 or not
        //===========================
        sub2 = null;
        str1 = null;
        str2 = null;
        strRes = null;
        sub2 = subA.slice(0, 2); //get first 2 digits of sub code
        // alert(sub2);
        str1 = "select AcCode from Account where AcCode='";
        str2 = str1 + sub2 + "'";
        //strRes = GetCodeData(str2);
        //strRes = GetCodeData(str2); //check whether 2 digits code exist or not
        GetCodeData(str2); //check whether 2 digits code exist or not
        //       alert(strRes);
        strRes = strRes.substring(1, strRes.length - 1);
        if (strRes.length === 0 || strRes == "") {

            alert("First Create Sub Code of Two Digits");
            return false;

        }
    } //end of sub code checking
    return true;
}
```

these function of javascript are displaying alerts during debugging in firefor (firebug) but without any breakpoint no alert is display on form and user dnt know what happened after save button click.

anyone help me to remove this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a form there which is submitted, and page gets refreshed after that, so you won't get result of your ajax request. Try handling "submit" event instead of a "click", prevent form submission (you can either use preventDefault, or return false in the end for this), and handle it by yourself

```
$('#form_id').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();    
var isValid = validateForm();
if (isValid) {

    //***********************CODE TO SAVE DATA IN DATABASE***********************************
    var person = { AcCode: $('#AcCode').val(), Descrip: $('#Descrip').val(), AddOn: dd };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Save?action=Sve',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(person),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            //   $('#message').html('Record saved successfully' + result).fadeIn();
            alert("Record saved successfully");
        },
        error: function () {
            //    $('#message').html('Error Occurred').fadeIn(); 
            alert("Record not saved successfully");
        }
    });
}
else
    alert("form is not valid");

return false;

});  //end button clcik function
```

Comment: plz tell me then how can i perform edit delete and cancel buttons operation if i perform validations on form submit

Comment: you can do it in several ways 
1) just replace <input type="submit"... with usual buttons so that they won't submit form and bind on click handlers for them 2) leave them as inputs with on "click" handlers, but prevent form from submission by $("#form_id").submit(function(){return false;})